# Colocar botones uno debajo de otro en caso de que se haga más pequeña la página

Tags: html, css

tengo un problema con el comportamiento de tres botones que tengo situados uno al lado del otro.
Cuando la página cambia a un tamaño más pequeño, siguen manteniendo ese orden cuando lo que busco es que se sitúen en ese caso, en vertical, es decir, uno encima de otro. ¿Cómo podría solventar esto?. A continuación adjunto parte del CSS y del código de los botones.

```css
.myButton {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #fff6af;
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffec64 5%, #ffab23 100%);
    background-color:#ffec64;
    border-radius:6px;
    border:1px solid #ffaa22;
    display:inline-block;
    cursor:pointer;
    color:#333333;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:6px 24px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:0px 1px 0px #ffee66;
}

.myButton:hover {
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffab23 5%, #ffec64 100%);
    background-color:#ffab23;
}
.myButton:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.bouncy{
animation:bouncy 5s infinite linear;
position:relative;
}
  
.bouncy2{
animation:bouncy 3s infinite linear;
position:relative;
}
  
@keyframes bouncy {
0%{top:0em}
40%{top:0em}
43%{top:-0.9em}
46%{top:0em}
48%{top:-0.4em}
50%{top:0em}
100%{top:0em;}
}
  
  
.btn-group .btn {
  width: 30%;
}
  
.btn-group {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group">
<button class="myButton btn-group btn">Boton1</button>
<button class="myButton bouncy2 btn-group btn">Boton2</button>
<button class="myButton btn-group btn">Boton3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPCIÓN 1**

Lo mas simple en estos casos sería:

- Al contenedor principal que tiene la clase `btn-group` dale un `display` con un valor de `flex`
- Como con el paso anterior los elementos internos se volvieron cajas flexibles entonces quedarían *pegados* uno a lado del otro (los botones); para corregir esto le damos un margin a los 4 lados de 5 px para que todos los botones queden separados
- Para lograr el efecto buscado que es se desplacen uno abajo del otro, podemos valernos de `flex-wrap` con un valor de `wrap` que nos ayudará a que si los elementos no quedan en la misma fila entonces los mande a una siguiente:

```html
    <style>
      .btn-group {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin: 5px;
      }
    </style>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button class="myButton btn-group btn">Boton1</button>
      <button class="myButton bouncy2 btn-group btn">Boton2</button>
      <button class="myButton btn-group btn">Boton3</button>
    </div>
```

**OPCIÓN 2**

A cada botón por medio de su clase le damos un ancho en porcentaje de 33%

Cuando el espacio no sea el necesario para que los botones sigan en fila serán
reacomodados en la siguiente, es aquí donde por medio de una media query indicamos
el punto de quiebre; es decir a partir de que medida habrá un reajuste

Para este ejemplo tomé los 700px y le indico al contenedor padre
que:

- alineará los elementos o botones al centro
- Les dará un ancho del 90% de si mismo

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .contenedor {
        border: 1px solid;
      }
      .contenedor-boton {
        width: 33%;
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .contenedor {
          text-align: center;
        }
        .contenedor-boton {
          width: 90%;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <div class="contenedor">
      <button class="contenedor-boton">Botón 1</button>
      <button class="contenedor-boton">Botón 2</button>
      <button class="contenedor-boton">Botón 3</button>
    </div>
```

Esta sería una forma de lograr que:

- Los botones ocupen el 33% de espacio cada uno
- Pasen de fila a columna y sean mas grandes cuando establezcamos una media query

Comment: No funciona correctamente tal y como yo lo quiero. Los botones tienen que expandirse por toda la pantalla y ocupar el 33% de la misma cada uno y al reducir el tamaño de la pantalla (para móviles generalmente) que se coloquen uno debajo de otro porque en horizontal se mezclan las letras que muestran :(

Comment: Bueno es que esos detalles se deben agregar a la pregunta, dame un rato y te modifico la respuesta

Comment: Si, por supuesto, cuando puedas. Gracias.

Comment: Hice una edición @user3224353 espero te sirva de guía

Answer (score 0):

Te aconsejaría trabajar sobre un framework de Css, para que no reinventes la rueda. En frameworks como bootstrap tienen clases especiales para los puntos de quiebre según el tamaño de la pantalla. Te dejo la documentación aquí y de otro.

- [Bootstrap v4.5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/)
- [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/)